# laravel php problems with array index get values

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
$category = Category::find($request->category_id);

$products = Product::whereIn('category_id', $category->subcategories->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();
```

How can get products with category ids

my code pulls products according to indexes, not according to ids. how do i get it to pull by id

Comment: Welcome to SO ... how is Product and Category related in the database schema?

Comment: OMG
i didn't pay any attention.
ty @lagbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$products = Product::whereIn('category_id', $category->subcategories->select('id')->get(['id'])->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

use code :

```
$category = Category::Query()->find($request->category_id);

$products = Product::Query()
    ->whereIn('category_id', $category->subcategories->select('id')->get(['id'])
        ->toArray());
```